# Jersey JAX-RS WebException is not thrown, instead status 404 is returned. Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs

I have a jax rs method that looks like this:

[image]

When an exception occurs while updating an employee a status 404 is returned, instead of the status 409 which is thrown with the WebException (extends WebApplicaitonException). I am sure that WebException is being thrown, but for some reason it returns the 404 status instead of the 409. What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Are you sure your `catch (Exception e)` has been reached? Maybe `404 Not Found` returned by the container which means the container couldn't find any resource requested.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate. If the link doesn't work for you, let me know, and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i searched everywhere and never saw that one! Jeez feel like a goof. Adding ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR in JerseyConfig worked for me, but setting the value in application.properties did not.